# Comparing two fields using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4.1, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm facing a weird problem. As shown in the image actually I selected record number 37 but lightswitch is highlighting as record number 1.
[image]
1) The FristName,LastName & HospitalName are unique indexes in the table Doctors since each doctor can have multiple addresses.

2) I'm validating this drop down field as below to avoid user from selecting doctors who are not part of the hospital patient belongs to.

```
partial void DoctorsMasterItem_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)
    {
        if (this.DoctorsMasterItem != null)
        {


            if (this.HospitalName != this.DoctorsMasterItem.HospitalName)
            {

                results.AddPropertyError("Make Sure the Hospital Patient belongs to and Doctor is also part of that hospital else your letters address would be wrong");

            }

        }

    }
```

The data model is

[image]

Comment: What's your question? I see only statements here.

Comment: The problem I'm having is I'm not able to select correct record. For example even though I select record # 37 in the image, it's actually showing record #1 and validation is failing. The realtionship between record #1 and #37 is that they have same firstName,LastName but diff hospital

Comment: This is not a problem with your validate it is a problem with the list select. Please post the code for that.

Comment: I'm using lightswitch so the list select code is generated automatically by LightSwitch. You think it could be a bug ? So I can report it ?

Comment: What code are you using to get the list from Lightswitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to **filter** the dropdown box, so the user isn't presented with invalid choices.

Have a look at these two articles. This is what I believe you should be doing, nested (or cascading) comboboxes:

[Nested AutoCompleteBox For Data Entry](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry/)

[Nested AutoCompleteBox for data entry Part 2](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Does it select the wrong row for any of the other duplicate names that have different hospitals? If so, it would be a clear indication that the hospital name is not being taken into consideration in whatever method is performing the selection. Do you have access to the code that's performing the select, or is there a way you can to ensure it's taking the hospital name into consideration? If it can be modified to take all three criteria into consideration, it should work as intended.

Comment: It is selecting duplicate names that different hospitals. Unfortunately I don't know where exactly is the code as I said earlier I'm using lightswitch and fairly new to C# or programming.